# Does using `aria-expanded` on a navigation bar even make sense?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, accessibility, semantic-markup, wai-aria

<sub>After a decade long hiatus I am dipping my toes into web development again. It still seems a very confusing heap of constantly changing standards to me, making it unclear which browsers support what and what the best practices are.</sub>

Currently, I am focusing on using the [new semantic elements of HTML5](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp). I found out the ASP.NET Core default Bootstrap template does not use the `<nav>` element for the navigation bar and was therefore looking into how to apply it properly.

The [default navbar template in Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) *does* recommend to use `<nav>`. However, I am confused as to what the purpose is behind the `aria-expanded` attribute applied to it. After [learning about the benefits it offers to screen readers](https://www.marcozehe.de/2010/02/10/easy-aria-tip-5-aria-expanded-and-aria-controls/) (indicating whether the navigation bar is collapsed or not, in this instance when the screen size is small, i.e., for smartphones), I am still confused as to whether it should be there at all. (And [whether or not `aria-controls` should be applied](http://www.heydonworks.com/article/aria-controls-is-poop), which it isn't in the default bootstrap template.)

Let me explain:

- Some of these aria attributes seem to be describing visual behavior. Does it even make sense to describe something to the non-sighted which they can not see?
- With the `<nav>` and `<main>` semantic elements applied correctly, don't the screen readers have all the necessary information at hand already to quickly skip the navigation bar (equivalent of hiding it for the sighted)?

Wouldn't a better alternative be to just hide the navigation toggle mechanism to the non-sighted altogether? Here my question then would be, how to go about this. Can a button be hidden [using `role="presentation"` and/or `aria-hidden="true"`](http://john.foliot.ca/aria-hidden/#pr)?

Comment: Do you have a functional example we can see? On the surface, you are asking a valid question about the need to represent something in ARIA when it is only a visual effect. The catch is that context is key, as well as the coding of course. With an example I can load it in a screen reader or look at the code and give you specific feedback.

Comment: @aardrian Perhaps [the official Bootstrap navbar example](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/)? Unfortunately this web page does not contain the `<main>` element I refer to in my question, but it might suit your purpose. It should also be easy enough to add it yourself after the nav bar (using F12).

Comment: @aardrian As to the context: the navigation bar in bootstrap by default can be collapsed or expanded on smaller screen sizes, i.e., smartphones. On larger screen sizes it is displayed at all times and no navigation bar toggle is visible. (I also added this context to the question.)

Answer (score 1):

Using the example you cite at https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/, it needs `aria-expanded`.

In the larger viewport, the "dropdown" menu hides all the sub-items. They are not only hidden visually, but hidden to screen readers as well. The `aria-expanded` helps give the user context whether or not there is more available, and also gives some clue about where the subsequent tab-stops may take the user.

In the narrower viewport, where the navigation becomes a hamburger, this still applies. Doubly so since it also applies to the hamburger itself.

This context is important since `aria-controls` support is poop (to quote Heydon).

There are cases where every item in a menu is available via tabbing, even if visually not there. In that case `aria-expanded` is not so important, but `aria-controls` would have more value.

Separately, that menu needs better `:focus` highlighting for sighted keyboard users, and DOM sequence for the menu versus logo in the narrow viewport (through that is my opinion).

Comment: I have been looking into how Bootstrap modifies the DOM to hide these elements, and I'm unclear about the mechanism. How is it that it is hidden _both_ visually and to screen readers? Also, more in line with my original question, _why_ would it need to be hidden from screen readers in the first place? Perhaps I do not fully understand how 'in practice' `aria-expanded` helps traversing (in this case, nested lists) the DOM. In addition, I wonder whether tabbing behavior for screen readers is the same or not as in normal browsers.

Comment: Tabbing behavior in screen readers is the same as normal browsers, because screen readers _rely_ on normal browsers. Screen readers add additional support for landmarks, controls, etc. Screen readers honor `display:none`, so it is easy to hide something from a screen reader with that style. In this case, the _why_ it is hidden is up to the developer. At the very least, it is a less verbose experience.

Comment: @StevenJeuris Keep asking, I would rather you get a sense of how SRs work that is accurate. I can also provide examples, resources, etc. if you want. Options abound.

Comment: Thank you for the info on tabbing behavior. That goes some way to explaining it! However, I do not notice Bootstrap introducing `display: none` (seemingly `::before` and `::after` is manipulated, which I do not understand how it works), but regardless of the mechanism used, tabbing no longer stops at the 'hidden' elements thus I understand the need for the aria attributes a bit better. Perhaps my underlying question would then be answered by having a better understanding of _why_ screen readers rely on browsers as they currently do.

Comment: For example, decoupling tabbing behavior or allowing it to be modified (e.g., through aria attributes) seems to me to be a more suitable approach to making websites more accessible. For the sighted, tabbing no longer stops at the elements since they are _no longer visible_, but this is a non-argument for the non-sighted. Wouldn't it make more sense to be able to skip over content based on semantic grouping, which is already achieved by wrapping elements in a parent element?

Comment: This is especially true in the case of the navigation bar with ordinary links (no containing dropdown boxes); the main reason the navigation links are hidden is because there is not enough screen space. That is what I refer to as a 'non-argument' for the non-sighted.

Comment: The best approach to making a web site accessible is by [using proper HTML](http://webaim.org/techniques/semanticstructure/). If done well, ARIA is only needed [for complex controls](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/) (tabs, trees, carousels, …). Screen readers allow [jumping to content based on landmarks](https://dequeuniversity.com/assets/html/jquery-summit/html5/slides/landmarks.html) (`<nav>`, `<main>`, `<footer>`, …), but still benefit the same way sighted users do from hidden elements. Also not all SR users are blind, so visuals should match.

Comment: A resource for SR testing: http://webaim.org/articles/screenreader_testing/
Quick demo of SR in use: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_ATY9gimOM

Answer (score 1):

> Some of these aria attributes seem to be describing visual behavior. Does it even make sense to describe something to the non-sighted which they can not see?

**That question should be the first to appear in any ARIA tutorial.**

> With the `<nav>` and `<main>` semantic elements applied correctly, don't the screen readers have all the necessary information at hand already to quickly skip the navigation bar (equivalent of hiding it for the sighted)?

**And this one the second.**

Edit: When I read those questions, I thought "that guy has already understood everything". ARIA tutorials rarely answer those questions because they are context dependent, but asking those questions must be the first step before using ARIA. *Eg. image carousels are for blind people a very different user experience. Giving an `aria-controls` attribute to the "previous" button does not give more intelligence to a system based on visual effects. ARIA is not a miraculous panacea.*

---

ARIA may be seen as a kind of magic potion for people wanting to make accessible something which is not accessible. In many cases it will be used ill-advisedly.

**The** `aria-expanded` **can give a good user experience for screenreaders, informing whether or not an element can be opened to show more elements** (for instance inside a dropdown menu).

You can't apply the `aria-expanded` directly on a `nav` element because it has to be set on an interactive element (like a `button`) to inform that this controls the visibility of another element inside the same container (*which can be a* `nav`).

The better alternative I can see is not hiding anything to also help people not using screenreaders. Instead of collapsing a navigation bar at small screen resolutions, it's perfectly possible to:

1. always show it
2. display a persistent menu icon to jump to the menu bar (or temporarily displaying it inside the viewport)

This has the benefit to enable the possibility to scroll to the menu bar (for people not understanding what that icon with three parallel lines may indicate) and let screenreaders users list all the internal links.

Of course, things are very different if you conceive a web application rather than a simple web site, and ARIA might be more useful in that context.

Comment: Are you claiming that those questions _are_ answered in most ARIA tutorials, or that they _should be_ and are not? I do not see how your answer works towards answering these two questions explicitly.

Comment: I edited my answer (in short "it's context dependent"). In fact, asking those questions is an answer by itself. The best choice is to make screenreaders users ignore what is the expected visual effect and give them the best user experience. ARIA is often a makeshift trying to make clear something that is not natively clear. Who really loves dropdown menu with hidden subitems? Does a "collapse/expanded" information does give more information than "Open menu" in plain english? We can use ARIA to improve navigation, but we must focus primarly on making websites accessible without ARIA.